# How to avoid IQKeyboard from scrolling up the navigation bar too?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using IQKeyboard (https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) to avoid keyboard hiding the textfields while writing on them.
However they also scroll up the navigation bar which I don't intend to do. How do I avoid this?

I'm using the following snippet for using the same in `AppDelegate`

```
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enableAutoToolbar = false
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().shouldShowToolbarPlaceholder = false
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().previousNextDisplayMode = IQPreviousNextDisplayMode.alwaysHide
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().keyboardDistanceFromTextField = 20
```

Comment: by just adding your textfields in scrollview ..

Comment: which version are you using? I think it works fine with version 6.1.1 (IQKeyboardManagerSwift (6.1.1))

Comment: No it's not working with IQKeyboardManagerSwift(v6.2.0)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to avoid `NavigationBar` to move up is put all your content inside `UIScrollView`

Check this from aurthor of `IQKeyboardManager` [Check this](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/issues/500#issuecomment-218425426)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to move all your content inside `UIScrollView` or you can use a navigation controller. By using navigation controller your problem will be solved.